# How to instantiate a custom iOS UIViewController and use it's NIB under Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib, nib

[image: StoryBoard setup]

I have a project with StoryBoard (iOS 5+), with two UIViewController.

The task would be to instantiate programmatically a second UIViewController (CoordinationController) but I'd like to use it's XIB file for the user interface design.

The evident workaround to copy the XIB to StoryBoard is not working or not usable for undocumented reasons.
Even the rule would be that in case the view controller of the second storyboard has no view it will look for the same named XIB... is not working.

How to instantiate the second UIViewController and use its XIB file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the nib file and set your view in an initWithCoder: method of CoordinationController:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CoordinationController" bundle:nil];
        NSArray *nibObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        self.view = nibObjects.lastObject;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: It's ok, thanks, but I'd like to see the instantiation in the FirstViewController too. Just a bonus question: could it work with segue too?

Comment: @BootMaker, I don't understand what you mean. Is FirstViewController also a subclass of CoordinationController?

Comment: No, it's a different controller, actually the first controller or RootController, but it's important how could it instantiate the CoordinationController.

Comment: @BootMaker, Do you mean you want to instantiate the CoordinationController fromFirstViewController? If so, just hook up a segue to it from FirstViewController. When the segue runs, the CoordinationController's iniWithCoder: method will be called.

Comment: Fine, thanks it's the answer to the bonus question. But actually my question was which code would you use to instantiate CoordinationController from FirstViewController without segue, I mean programmatically?

Comment: @BootMaker, If you want to instantiate it in code, then you just do it the normal way for a controller and nib -- [[CoordinationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoordinationController" bundle:nil];

Comment: it means twice call and actually the CoordinationController will not appear just instantiate, and be aware that I need the storyboard. Meantime I have the solution but it would be better to make a complete code and I could accept it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27428/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-bootmaker)

Comment: This is great for subclassing view controllers and still reuse the parents controller nib file

Answer (score 5):

A very simple solution is to override the view controller's `nibName` property and return the name of the nib that encodes the view you want loaded:

```
- (NSString*) nibName
{
    NSLog( @"p.s. this is the nib that the storyboard generated: %@", [super nibName]);

    return @"MyViewController";
}
```

Note that you can access the name of the nib generated by the storyboard compiler, which would have been used.  This nib is included in the app bundle, packaged inside the storyboard.storyboardc bundle.

I am somewhat surprised that you cannot return nil from this nibName implementation and get the default behavior where the loader searches for a nib using the [rules described in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName).

Alternatively (and this is cheating) you could set the desired nib name in the Storyboard itself for the view controller via a user-defined runtime attribute with key nibName.  This works because there is an undocumented setter for the property, so don't actually do this!

I think this is a better solution than the accepted answer because the view will be loaded in the normal course of the view-controller's lifecycle - that is, it will be lazily loaded before the controller is presented vs up front in the init method.  And it is less code.

Comment: I had a situtation where I needed to display multiple .xibs but only using a single view controller.  I solved it using this and a singleton.  The .xib name was set in the singleton property, NSString *xibName.  Then the view controller was instantiated from the storyboard.  Inside - (NSString *) nibName I added a line that got and returned xibName.  Worked perfectly.